# LNK 2019 when adding a new class to solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

i'm have a macro for debugging called DBGPRINT and i added a new class to my solution (including a .cpp and a .h file) by clicking in the project that i was interested in >> add new item >>copy my code to that files , i included the header and it all compiles correctly no problems when the macro DBGPRINT looks like this:

```
    #include <My_class_full_path.h>

    static char str[256];


     #define DBGPRINT(...) { sprintf_s(str, 190, "P:%08X  ",      GetCurrentThreadId() );  sprintf_s(str+11, (2048 - 11), __VA_ARGS__);  OutputDebugStringA(str)}
```

my class is in the My_class_full_path.H header. this class is actually a singelton and i want to call instance of it inside the DBGPPRINT macro so when I do this :

```
   #define DBGPRINT(...)         { sprintf_s(tempStingFordebug+11, (256 - 11), __VA_ARGS__);  my_class::getInstance(); OutputDebugStringA(tempStingFordebug)}
```

i get lots of LNK2019 errors :

```
   Error    1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ...
```

the 3 dots are functions names from other projects in my solution.

the file with the DBGPRINT function is included in almost every source file inside my solution.

I saw in the internet solutions of including things inside the linker but it is a simple header file that I created so i dont understand what seem to be the problem...

EDIT: 
PROBLEM SOLVED: Using __declspec(dllimport) and __declspec(dllexport) to export my class to other DLL's

Comment: If these functions are defined in other projects, you should verify that the library (if the other projects build static libraries) or import libraries (if the other projects build DLLs) are linked to your program. The lazy way is to set projects dependencies.

Comment: You probably want a [tag:visual-studio] tag.

Comment: If the problem is solved, don't edit your question, provide and accept your own answer.